# How to Pass db properties while create gradle build

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-devops, devops

eg :
1.
gradel.build

gradle build -Pdb_server=$server -Pdb_port=$port -Pdb_database=$db_name -Pdb_username=$username -Pdb_password=$password

this i want to pass through commands line

2. Read db properties in application.properties
   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${db_server}:5432/${db_database}

spring.datasource.username=${db_username}
spring.datasource.password=${db_password}

Answer (score 0):

Issue got fixed by adding processResources task in build.gradle file. Now able to fetch dbServer, dbName, dbUsername, dbPassword from Gradle build project parameters.
Gradle Build command: gradle build -PdbUsername=test -PdbPassword=password

```
processResources {
    filesMatching("**/application.properties") {
        expand( project.properties )
    }
}
```